# Ubuntu 14.04 Install Error with Windows 7 Install Inside

Tags: 14.04, system-installation, wubi

I am using Windows 7 64 bit on my PC and installed Ubuntu 12.10 version with the "install inside" option. After the release of 14.04 I uninstalled the earlier version and installed the newer version. But it is not working correctly or loading after the complete installation process. I installed it with the Install inside option as well. The error messages shown are below.

[image]

When Manual Recovery option is selected

[image]

[Video Adept](http://www.videoadept.com)

Comment: Did you install it using wubi?

Comment: yes i installed it using wubi

Comment: well don't downvote I was giving an honest answer

Comment: is there any manual correction method for the above problem?

Comment: Wubi is no longer supported and you shouldn't install it using wubi. Try Google on how to install Ubuntu 14.04 alongside Windows 7.

Comment: I installed ubuntu 14.04 along with windows 7 and after that ubuntu is working fine and windows 7 is not booting. I searched in the internet and done a boot repair as shown here [link](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RestoreUbuntu/XP/Vista/7Bootloader) and windows boot menu restored. But again ubuntu showing same message as I shown in the question and not working now :(

Comment: @sbergeron I didn't voted for your Answer.

Comment: the problem is not solved yet [New thred](http://askubuntu.com/questions/503695/ubuntu-14-04-problem-with-windows-7-boot-menu)

Answer (score 2):

As you have installed **Ubuntu** inside **Windows 7**, select Ubuntu from the Windows boot manager and then you will see the **Ubuntu GNU Grub2** menu.

Or after you select "Ubuntu" from the Windows boot manager, keep <kbd>Shift</kbd> and the Grub menu should appear.

Then press `e` to start editing the boot entry.
And now you need to change a line in the GRUB2 boot entry from `ro` to `rw`.

You will see a line similar to this:

```
linux   /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-24-generic root=UUID=AAC884AC1F144321 loop=/ubuntu/disks/root.disk ro   quiet splash $vt_handoff
```

Replace `ro` with `rw` and finally the code will look like:

```
linux   /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-24-generic root=UUID=AAC884AC1F144321 loop=/ubuntu/disks/root.disk rw   quiet splash $vt_handoff
```

Press <kbd>F10</kbd> and you are done!

This is only to boot Ubuntu for a single time. You have to repeat these steps every-time you reboot. But you can change the `grub.cfg` permanently to avoid this issue. Follow these steps to edit the `grub.cfg` file after logging in to Ubuntu.

Open terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>T</kbd>)

Type:

```
sudo -H gedit /boot/grub/grub.cfg
```

and press enter.

Gedit will open with the `grub.cfg` file.

Press <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>F</kbd> open 'find' box on gedit.

Type `ro` in the find box. (Remember to type a space after `ro` - should be `ro`, not `ro`)

Search results will be highlighted and then change all those `ro`s to `rw`s. (replace `ro` with `rw`)

Save the file and reboot.