# Ubuntu 14.04 Problem With Windows 7 boot menu

Tags: boot, dual-boot, windows-7

I have asked a question previously [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/503532/ubuntu-14-04-install-error-with-windows-7-install-inside?noredirect=1), regarding installing Ubuntu inside Windows 7.
But the answer was Ubuntu install inside option is having various errors.
So I decided to install Ubuntu along with Windows 7 as everybody does. After that Ubuntu works perfectly and Windows 7 is not booting. So I searched in this forum and found a solution [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RestoreUbuntu/XP/Vista/7Bootloader).

Now Windows 7 is working perfectly and Ubuntu is unable to boot. The same error message again appeared. 
[image]

The Disk Management Snapshot:
[image]

http://paste.ubuntu.com/7885380/

Comment: Please provide the details: Firmware type UEFI/BIOS, Motherboard Chip-set details, Hard disk interface/model/size, possibly a snapshot of Windows 7 Disk Management console.

Comment: added system details. Disk Management is [here](http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-9PJqMDFf0X0/U9ZU8EI321I/AAAAAAAAJiA/djREZ2EaBvE/s1600/dskmng.JPG)

Answer (score 0):

It appears that partition ordering has some issues. As seen in the snapshot, the 4th partition 17.01 GB (I guess this is going to be '/') and the 5th partition 2.99 GB (and this is going to be 'swap') are out of Extended partition (Green box). This must have confused your Linux installation. Please try these:

- Restore the Windows bootloader as instructed  in https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RestoreUbuntu/XP/Vista/7Bootloader
- Boot from Windows
- Go to Windows Disk Management, delete the 4th and 5th partitions, assuming those were created for Linux
- You should now see ~20 GB of free space
- Right-click on the Extended partition and select Extend Partition in the menu
- Select all the free space and complete the dialog
- There should be 1 Primary and 1 Extended partitions now
- Inside the Extended partition, create the partitions for Linux as you wish
- Make sure the partitions that were created just now, fall inside the Extended partition
- Install Ubuntu into these partitions and report back the status ;-)

-- Wish you good luck

Comment: You are right with the assumptions. I created a 20 GB free space for the ubuntu installation and installed it with the option "Install Along with windows 7". And the ubuntu itself created the 20 GB into 17.01 and 2.99 GB partitions. In your answer how this can be done "Inside the Extended partition, create the partitions for Linux as you wish"

Comment: Alright. This time please boot the system from the Ubuntu installation media (CD/USB) and install it directly from Live. I would suggest avoiding WUBI method. Please just be very careful in the partition screen during the installation. If you are not confident, I strongly recommend you to go through the Ubuntu installer partitioning documentation.

Comment: I have done as you suggested. Whether I want to make a new drive in windows 7 or just use the free space as shown [here](http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-wxcC3Xagt2o/U9ZpGc7xgKI/AAAAAAAAJic/spU-jJQIH7A/s1600/DSC_0036.JPG) and install ubuntu in the 20GB space. Thank you

Comment: Just to make things go smooth, please create partitions using Windows Disk Management, right click on the free space and create two partitions (1 for '/' and 1 for 'swap') for Linux. Now, restart the system, set it to boot from the installation media, start the installer and choose the 'Manual (I want to do something else)' option in the partitioning step during installation and choose the last two partitions for your Linux installation. Ideally, largest size is for '/' (root) partition and the smaller one is for 'swap' partition.

Comment: Still having the same issue.[Ubuntu Report](http://paste.ubuntu.com/7885380/)

Comment: Please DO NOT use WUBI to install Ubuntu. Boot directly from installation media and select 'Install Ubuntu' inside the Live Ubuntu. Adding to this, if your system is based on UEFI, then it is going to be worse. :-[ try reading https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFIBooting

Comment: I didn't used WUBI to install ubuntu. I installed it through live USB media, and my system is old one and doesn't support UEFI

Comment: Please provide the: `dmesg` / `lspci` / `lsusb` logs from Ubuntu running live in your system.

Comment: I am unable to boot ubuntu now and I can give the [Ubuntu pastebin link](http://paste.ubuntu.com/7885380/)

Comment: The system information and the system logs are quite essential for any troubleshooting. Without them it is very difficult to ascertain the cause of the problem.

Comment: Okay. But I think it is better to use ubuntu 12 rather than this buggy 14 version. I installed version 12 perfectly. And thanks for your help