# Unable to boot from USB

Tags: dual-boot, lubuntu

I'm trying to install Lubuntu as a dual boot, but I can't boot from my USB.

I went into BIOS and changed the order, but the order just resets when I restart my computer even if I save the changes in the bios.

So I tried to install the wubi offers when I can't boot from CD, but I get an error saying

> An error occurred Could not retrieve the required installation files.
>   For more information, please see log file:

[Contents of the log file](http://shrib.com/m7XWCITe).
Does anyone know how to solve this?

Because this didnt work. I tried to remake the drive. And for some reason now the wubi gets installed instead of lubuntu itself.
When I double click the usb from my computer. Instead of prompting to rebootn it shows the wubi option screen where 30gb is the max... i honestly have no idea what is going on..

Comment: Are you trying to use Wubi or trying to dual-boot?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

USB boot is flaky on some devices. If you can live with DVD boot and save your data either to a USB or SD, that's much easier to setup and more reliable.

Comment: Found a dvd and tried it with infraboot??or the program similar with that name.. and it worked. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Sadly, some machines wil keep resetting the boot order -- even if not running Windows, even if you set an admin password.  On those, you may have to play games with renaming the bootloader, like boot-repair does, or just use the efi boot menu to select the boot device each time. ---

---

I don't think wubi is a working option anymore, so avoid it. What machine do you have, they all have individual quirks.  When you say you cannot select USB, what do you mean?  Do you get the efi menu of devices to boot, and don't see usb in the list?  How did you create the USB?  Did you md5sum hashcheck the downloaded iso file, and did you burn the CD as slowly as possible, and media check it afterward?

Comment: But, I just can't select the boot  device.. the usb won't boot at all... only windows boots..

Comment: I'm using lenovo ideapad Y510P. Not wubi. But dual boot. I see usb as an obtion. But I cant change the order. It just wont save what I changed. I created it with the universal usb installer. I checked the md5sum.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this helps.  On some computers with some flash drives, the flash drive is recognized as another hard drive.  Go back into the BIOS and look at the boot order.  If there is a + sign next to the hard drive check to see if your flash drive is there.  If it is, then move it ahead of the hard drive.  Save the settings, exit, and continue the boot.

Comment: It said that the USB was a boot option, so I put it on the top, but when I restart my computer after saving the setting, the order just resets and it just boots windows..

Comment: Maybe you need to press a "Save and exit" key or something to exit your BIOS.

Comment: F10 save and exit -> Yes. That's what I did

Answer (score 0):

**This message is regarding WUBI installer.**

You can install the version up to 13 through WUBI but installation of newest version through WUBI has much [error](https://askubuntu.com/questions/503532/ubuntu-14-04-install-error-with-windows-7-install-inside?noredirect=1)

**Steps to do before WUBI Installation**

- Disconnect your Internet Connection
- Copy the WUBI installer from the DVD/CD/USB to desktop
- And Run the Installer. Then the error message will not appear.

**For Dual Boot**

While Switching on Your PC You can Press The F12 key So that you can select your USB the device to boot from . (Please insert only the Ubuntu Software containing USB remove other pendrives from your PC)

You can use [Universal USB installer](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/universal-usb-installer-easy-as-1-2-3/) to create a bootable USB.

You can also check [bios Update for your PC](http://www.pcworld.com/article/187437/how_to_update_your_bios.html)

If this fails the best method is to burn Ubuntu on a DVD and directly boot. Because some Old PC is not good with USB boot.

Hope this will work for you.
Regards

Comment: I'm trying a dual boot. Not wubi.

Comment: hope your problem is solved. If not the answer is updated

Comment: YEah.. I created a dvd and now it works. thanks for the helps